# Fuzzy Matching in SnowFlake like EDIT_DISTANCE_SIMILARITY

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Do we have any function for name fuzzy matching like we have  UTL_MATCHING.EDIT_DISTANCE_SIMILARITY  in oracle. I have to find the difference at row level.

Answer (score 5):

Snowflake has EDITDISTANCE and SOUNDEX functions:

```
select editdistance('Duningham', 'Cunningham');
-- Result 2

select soundex('McArthur') = soundex('MacArthur');
-- Result TRUE
```

For EDITDISTANCE, unlike EDIT_DISTANCE_SIMILARITY lower scores are closer matches. There are many open source JavaScript implementations of fuzzy matching that you could plug into a Snowflake JavaScript UDF.